# Number of Quadratic Extensions of Locally Compact Fields

Tags: number-theory, local-field

I just got done with the proof of the following theorem:

Let $(K, |\cdot|)$ a locally compact nonarchimedean field with normalized discrete valuation $v$ and residue field $\mathbb{F}_q$. Let $m$ a positive integer not divisible by the characteristic of $K$, and let $\mu_m(K)$ the $m$-th roots of unity in $K$. Let $U$ be the unit group of $K$ (which is $v^{-1}(0)$), and let $U^n$ be the $n$-th higher unit group $1 + \mathfrak m^n$, where $\mathfrak m$ is the maximal ideal of the valuation ring $R$. Then

$$[U^* : U^{*m}] = q^{v(m)}\cdot \# \mu_m(K)$$

The following result is supposed to be a corollary of the above theorem, but I do not see why that is the case:

Let $(K, v, \pi, k)$ a locally compact field of characteristic $\neq 2$. Here $v$ is a valuation, $\pi$ is a uniformizer, and $k$ is the residue field. If the characteristic of $k > 2$, there are exactly $3$ quadratic extensions of $K$. If the characteristic of $k = 2$, there are exactly $2^{[K : \mathbb{Q}_p] + 2}-1$ quadratic extensions of $K$.

How can I see this?

Comment: For all fields $K$ not of characteristic $2$ (we allow local fields $K$ of characteristic $0$ whose *residue field* $k$ has characteristic $2$), the distinct quadratic extensions of $K$ are in $1$-$1$ correspondence with the nontrivial elements of $K^\times/(K^\times)^2$ ("square classes") by associating to a nonsquare $d \in K^\times$ the field $K(\sqrt{d})$. Thus compute $|K^\times/(K^\times)^2| - 1$.  When $K$ is a local field with prime $\pi$, $K^\times = \pi^{\mathbf Z} \times U \cong \mathbf Z \times U$, so $K^\times/(K^\times)^2 \cong \mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z \times U/U^2$.

Comment: I see, that helps! Is there some way I am to know what $v(2)$ is supposed to be?

Comment: You said what $v$ is: the *normalized discrete valuation on* $K$.  You need to understand what $v$ actually means and then it is straightforward to compute $v(2)$. If you don't understand what $v$ actually means, then reread whatever reference you are using in order to figure it out.